# Micronaut: problem with getting bean from context

Tags: java, dependency-injection, micronaut

I have a class that contain injections and mandatory(final) fields. For common I can use MicronautBeanFactory.getBean(type) OR BeanContext.getBean(type) to get bean from context, but in this situation I must pass type and args.

I've created simple test for this

```
@MicronautTest
public class ETLExecutorTest {

    @Inject
    private MicronautBeanFactory micronautBeanFactory;

    @Test
    void testGetBean() {
        Object[] args = new Object[] {"name", "spec", 1L};
        ObjectInstance instance = micronautBeanFactory.getBean(ObjectInstance.class, args);
    }
}
```

Object(bean) code

```
@Prototype
public class ObjectInstance {

    @Inject
    private ObjectStorage objectStorage;

    private final String name;
    private final String spec;
    private final Long id;

    public ObjectInstance(String name, String spec, Long id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.spec = spec;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When I run it I receive exception

> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [name] of class: com.ObjectInstance
>   Message: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String]
>   Path Taken: new ObjectInstance([String name],String specName,Long accountId)
>   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1016)
>   at com.$TableInstanceDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1598)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getScopedBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2076)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1991)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1963)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:610)
>   at io.micronaut.spring.context.factory.MicronautBeanFactory.getBean(MicronautBeanFactory.java:264)
>   Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NonUniqueBeanException: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String]
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultBeanContext.java:1701)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultApplicationContext.java:395)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lastChanceResolve(DefaultBeanContext.java:2289)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidateNoCache(DefaultBeanContext.java:2212)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lambda$findConcreteCandidate$57(DefaultBeanContext.java:2155)
>   at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.lambda$compute$0(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:721)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
>   at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.compute(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:733)
>   at io.micronaut.core.util.clhm.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.java:710)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultBeanContext.java:2154)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1943)
>   at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1082)
>   at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1007)

Also I tried to do another test, but in this case I receive object without injected fields

```
@MicronautTest
public class ETLExecutorTest {

    @Inject
    private BeanContext beanContext;

    @Test
    void testGetBean() {
        Object[] args = new Object[] {"name", "spec", 1L};
        BeanDefinition<ObjectInstance> definition = beanContext.getBeanDefinition(ObjectInstance.class);
        ObjectInstance instance =  definition.getConstructor().invoke(args); // there are no injections here: ObjectStorage of instance = null.
    }
}
```

Could you tell me, please, what I do wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`micronaut` trying to create bean `ObjectInstance` through the **constructor** but can't find `String name` to inject, looks like it’s just a simple field for the `ObjectInstance` and  in this case, it works as expected:

> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [name]

if you add a default constructor, then the `ObjectInstance`  will be created and you can get bean via `beanContext.getBean(ObjectInstance.class)`:

```java
@Prototype
public class ObjectInstance {

    @Inject
    private ObjectStorage objectStorage;

    private String name;
    private String spec;
    private Long id;


    public ObjectInstance() {}

    public ObjectInstance(String name, String spec, Long id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.spec = spec;
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Also pay attention to [MicronautBeanFactory](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-spring/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/io/micronaut/spring/context/factory/MicronautBeanFactory.java) implements [ListableBeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html), this is for integration with `Spring`

P.S. I would recommend you change your code structure, `POJO` should not contain `beans`

Comment: Yes, you are right about MicronautBeanFactory - it joined with spring. When we look at MicronautBeanFactory.getBean() we would see that it throw org.springframework.beans.BeansException. Yes, your offer(default constructor) it is good variant to resolve it. @tsarenkotxt Thanks for your advice. What about my second test where args are applyed to construstor, but ObjectStorage was not injected ?
Could we force micronaut to inject this bean during `definition.getConstructor().invoke(args);` ???

Comment: you can use `.invoke(args)`, but in this case, you get just an instance that is not in the context, if this option is suitable in your test after you can inject `ObjectStorage` to `ObjectInstance` through a setter `objectInstance.setObjectStorage(beanContext.getBean(ObjectStorage.class))`,  also you can inject `ObjectInstance` into the context manually `beanContext.registerSingleton(objectInstance)`. to be honest, I'm not sure if this is a good solution `force`

Comment: I used your first idea. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried these suggestions on Micronaut 2.2.0 and found that you should annotate constructor arguments with @Parameter annotation to have them considered while constructing as in 
 `public ObjectInstance(@Parameter String name, @Parameter String spec, @Parameter Long id)`.
 Then you may create a Bean and have it put into context using the createBean method from ApplicationContext as 
`applicationContext.createBean(ObjectInstance.class, arg1, arg2, arg3)`